# Making icon bigger

Tags: php, icons

What i am trying to do is to create sections with an icon and title. but i can make the icon in the same size with title. This is the code:

```
$section = array('css' => 'icon-user', 'title' => 'Lau');
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                if($counter %4==0){
                  echo icon_input($section['css'],'<h3 class="header medium lighter blue">'.$section['title'].'</h3>');
                }
```

it shows me icon up and small and bottom is the title , i want them next to each other

Comment: Your code helps nothing, but if I understand correctly, you are asking on how to make your HTML elements float next to each other.

Comment: Are you using any css frameworks for generating icon?

Comment: yes and the same size. because if i put $section['css'] inside <h3> it shows me the name of icon and not the icon.